# ruby hash add key/value if modifier

Tags: ruby, hash

I am working with a ruby `hash` that contains key/value pairs for creating a new subscriber in my MailChimp API.

```
user_information = {
    'fname' => 'hello world',
    'mmerge1' => 'Product X' if user.product_name.present?
}
```

Obviously, I am getting a syntax error of `syntax error, unexpected modifier_if`... I am basically only wanting to add the `mmerge1` based upon the conditional being true.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't use `if` that way, inside a hash-initialization block. You'll have to conditionally add the new key/value after initializing the hash:

```
user_information = {
    'fname' => 'hello world',
}

user_information['mmerge1'] = 'Product X' if user.product_name.present?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
user_information = {'fname' => 'hello world'}
user_information.merge!({'mmerge1' => 'Product X'}) if user.product_name.present?
#=> {"fname"=>"hello world", "mmerge1"=>"Product X"}
```

Comment: The `merge!` is adding a lot of unneeded complexity for a single key/value.

Comment: On the other hand, `merge!` is useful when adding *multiple* values.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a conditional expression on the key you get a reasonably readable syntax and, at most, need to remove only 1 element from the Hash.

```
product_name = false
extra_name = false

user_information = {
  'fname' => 'hello world',
  product_name ? :mmerge1 : nil => 'Product X',
  extra_name ? :xmerge1 : nil => 'Extra X'
}
user_information.delete nil

p user_information
```

Answer (score 0):

If `mmerge1` is allowed to be `nil` or an empty string, you can use the `?:` ternary operator inside the hash:

```
user_information = {
  'fname' => 'hello world',
  'mmerge1' => user.product_name.present? ? 'Product X' : ''
}
```

Comment: You could make it `nil` and call `compact`, or do `reject(&:blank?)`.

Comment: Many methods will interpret the *presence* of a key as setting that option so this is not a good pattern to use in general practice.